# Searching for Re-occurances in EXCEL and using those Re-occurances

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a function that looks to see if the value of a field, lets say "A1", occurs elsewhere in the "A" column, and then searches the rows of those re-occurances and if any of those rows matches a "condition" (i.e. one of them has Yes, where the rest has No), it would then return `<some value>`.

The current fuction I am using is this:

```
=IF(AND(AZ12="yes", ISBLANK(AS12)),"NO - nil return status",IF(AND(AY12="C", ISBLANK(AS12)),"NO - annual return",IF(ISBLANK(AS12),"NO","YES")))
```

I would like to make it search every row that contains the same value in Column A, not just the Row its currently set as

Comment: So, you want to search for a string, if the string exists in any cell in a given column, then where does this result get displayed ("XYZ")? And what does this have to do with reoccurances?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please present some form of effort and/or research. Have you searched? What solution did you come up with? Did it work in part? You might also want to provide some sample data to illustrate the functionality you're looking for. Maybe even add a second sentence to your question to elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply - the result would be displayed in a cell that the occurrence appeared.

Comment: I shall try to clarify the issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - using the following command

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,COUNTIF(BB:BB,"Yes")>0),"Yes","No")
```

Thanks for your assistance